# What is the correct JUJU charm for Kubernetes?

Tags: juju, kubernetes

I've found 2 charms relative to "The charmed distribution of kubernetes".

The first at https://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/ seems to have only the necessary components.

The second at https://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/2 adds topbeat filebeat elastic search and kibana.

Strangely the two charms say they are installed with the command "juju deploy canonical-kubernetes"

So my questions:

- what is the correct charm?
- what charm will be installed with the command "juju deploy canonical-kubernetes"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation seems to give conflicting results. To be sure of what you will deploy with `juju deploy canonical-kubernetes` you can do the following:

```
$ juju deploy canonical-kubernetes --dry-run
Located bundle "cs:bundle/canonical-kubernetes-471"
```

You can also copy the command on the top right to ensure you get the version you want. So for the bundle with filebeat / ES it would be `juju deploy cs:bundle/canonical-kubernetes-2`.

A word of caution, the bundle with the elasticsearch that you linked does not seem to be updated and uses old charms. You can find the charm version in de bundle.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

### What is the correct Juju charm for Kubernetes?

There are two main choices for running Kubernetes under Juju:

- kubernetes-core
- canonical-kubernetes

The `kubernetes-core` is a minimalist installation that's typically faster. It's perfect for getting started with k8s. `canonical-kubernetes` is the [Charmed Distribution of Kubernetes](https://www.ubuntu.com/kubernetes) and suitable for production workloads.

### What version of the charm is used when I run `juju deploy`?

Juju will attempt to resolve the most recent charm or bundle. To identify which version of the charm or bundle is current, you can visit the [charm store](http://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/) or use the command-line:

```
juju deploy canonical-kubernetes --dry-run
```

If you don't trust `--dry-run` for whatever reason, you could spin up a local test using [LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/), then deploy the charm there:

```
juju bootstrap localhost k8s
juju deploy canonical-kubernetes
```

You'll then see something similar to the following:

```
Located bundle "cs:bundle/canonical-kubernetes-499"
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/easyrsa-235
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/etcd-415
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/flannel-404
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/kubeapi-load-balancer-628
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/kubernetes-master-654
Resolving charm: cs:~containers/kubernetes-worker-519
Executing changes:
- upload charm cs:~containers/easyrsa-235 for series bionic
- deploy application easyrsa on bionic using cs:~containers/easyrsa-235
  added resource easyrsa
- set annotations for easyrsa
- upload charm cs:~containers/etcd-415 for series bionic
- deploy application etcd on bionic using cs:~containers/etcd-415
  added resource etcd
  added resource snapshot
- set annotations for etcd
- upload charm cs:~containers/flannel-404 for series bionic
- deploy application flannel on bionic using cs:~containers/flannel-404
  added resource flannel-amd64
  added resource flannel-arm64
  added resource flannel-s390x
- set annotations for flannel
...
Deploy of bundle completed.
```